# What is the correct syntax for setting the apply method in AWS::RDS::DBParameterGroup in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-dbparametergroup.html) for DBParameter group's `Parameters` states the following:

```
An array of parameter names, values, and the apply method for the parameter update. At least one parameter name, value, and apply method must be supplied; subsequent arguments are optional. A maximum of 20 parameters may be modified in a single request. For more information, see Working with DB Parameter Groups in the Amazon RDS User Guide.

MySQL

Valid Values (for Apply method): immediate | pending-reboot

You can use the immediate value with dynamic parameters only. You can use the pending-reboot value for both dynamic and static parameters, and changes are applied when DB Instance reboots.
```

I would like to set the apply method to `immediate` for both of the following parameters:

```
      Parameters:
        character_set_server: utf8mb4
        collation_server: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

What is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Sadly, even though the doc says so, I don't think it's supported by CloudFormation at all.

Answer (score 0):

From [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html):

> If you change a parameter value, when the change is applied is
>   determined by the type of parameter. Changes to dynamic parameters are
>   applied immediately. Changes to static parameters require that the DB
>   instances associated with DB cluster that uses the DB cluster
>   parameter group be rebooted before the change takes effect. To
>   determine the type of a parameter, list the parameters in a parameter
>   group using one of the procedures shown in the section Listing DB
>   Parameter Groups.

From the AWS console, under RDS > Parameter Groups, you can see that both the parameters you mentioned are dynamic parameters.

[image: Parameter group character_set_server]
[image]

So when you update the Cloudformation stack, your changes to the parameter groups would apply immediately.

Comment: I'm talking about the initial creation of the stack. The settings aren't applied immediately then and I would like them to be applied then.